# No module named scipy.misc

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to set up my python for some works, but I'm struggling so much!
I need to use python3.4 and the scipy module.

I built the scipy module using the `python3 setup.py install` command from the terminal, but when I try to import the **imread function** from the scipy.misc module is says that

```
No module named scipy.misc is found.
```

I read that I need to install PIL or Pillow, but I already did that.

What do I have to do now?

Comment: what does `import sys, sys.path` say ?

Comment: Can you please show your code ?

Comment: @HaseebR7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2195, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'sys.path'; 'sys' is not a package

Comment: @Noob I'm just importing the modules, I'm not doing anything else. If I do from scipy.misc import imread and import scipy.misc I have the same results: No module named scipy.misc

Comment: What does `$ python -c "import scipy; scipy.test()"` output?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `./script.py`?

In many cases, a script will be hard coded to use the system's python installation, but maybe you installed scipy in a virtualenv or conda env.

So make sure the first "shebang" line in the script shows the path of the python for which you installed scipy. If it's hard coded, please consider `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead.

Are you calling `python script.py`?

If so, then make sure `which python` shows the right path.

Answer (score 0):

There is a distribution of Python and other tools called Anaconda which solves many of the install issues like this.
Note: After an install, restart the terminal it should set the path for you if you checked the checkbox to do that.
Use `pip install <package>`, or `conda install <package>` only use `python setup.py install` if neither of those work, or even better yet you can use the user interface (Anaconda Navigator) to do all this without opening the terminal.

[download link](https://www.anaconda.com/download/)

Hope this helps.